# Treating outlier value while plotting line chart in seaborn Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following data set that I would like to plot:
column growth rate is in % meaning 0.01 = 1%

```
month      country       growth_rate
2018-01    DE            0.01
2018-02    DE            0.05
2018-03    DE            0.07
2018-01    IN            0.01
2019-02    IN            325.01
2019-03    IN            0.05
```

Now I will plot the above data with the following code : `sns.lineplot(data=df, x="month", y="growth_rate", hue="country")`  
But the chart I am getting is too skewed for the country IN as one of the values is too huge- 325.01 and the rest of the values are suppressed by that and not shown correctly on the trend

What is the best way to treat this? Can I scale down somehow to still show the impact of that huge growth and also show the trend of other values in the data frame?

Comment: _What is the best way to treat this?_ is asking for an opinion, and opinion based questions are off-topic. Questions should be specific, not open ended. As such, _how can I scale my axis to show all the values?_ or _how can I remove outliers from my data?_ are the correct type of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about setting a log scale on the y-axis?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set(yscale="log")

sns.lineplot(data=df, x="month", y="growth_rate", ax = ax, hue="country")
```

Comment: this works! thank! but is there a way that I can show the y axis values in human-readable format? as of now, for another chart of mine, I am getting 3*10^6 as an example value which is essentially 3 billion. So how to transform the value as 3B or 3M for that matter?